# TChart issue: Bars of my Bar-Chart should be spread equally and not overlap

Tags: delphi, teechart

I'm developing an application, written in Delphi.
I use the TChart-Component to show/generate a Bar-Chart.
On my X-Axis, there are Date values.
On my Y-Axis, there is numeric data.
My dataset looks like:
    [DataSet-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GtKw.png)

When I generate my Chart, the Bars overlap, because the spread of the values of my X-axis is not equal (sometime, there are 7 days between 2 dates, sometimes it will be > 30 days).
Example of my chart:
[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsOjB.png)

Is there a way to equally spread the bars, so that they are not overlapping (so not taking into account the gaps between 2 dates on the X-Axis)?

Thanks already for all your help and support.

Comment: Use row number for x-axis instead of datum column and show the dates on labels. I would try to edit it if you shared the code.

Comment: Hi sddk, I tried your suggestion and it works like a charm! Never tought that the solution would be that simple. How can I mark your comment as the solution to my problem?

Comment: I'll write it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use row number for x-axis instead of datum column and show the dates on labels.